# How to call a subclass from other subclass which are under a outer class

Tags: java

```
class Test {
    void method2() {
        System.out.println("This is outer class method");
    }


    static class M2 {
        void method1() {
            System.out.println("This is method1 in class m2");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        //test a=new test();
        //a.method2();
    }
}
```

I want to call method1 which is in class M2 from main class. And also method2 from method1.

Comment: `new Test.M2().method1()` and `new Test().method2()`

Comment: Without an instance of M2, I think you need to put method1 static as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call *method2* from *method1*, you have to create an instance of `Test` class, since you're in a *static* context inside *method1*.

```
new Test().method2();
```

---

And to call *method1* from *main*:

```
new Test.M2().method1();
```

Since, `M2`, is a nested class, you can access it directly on outer class name - *Test*. Had it been an inner class, you would have to create an instance of `Test` to access it:

```
new Test().new M2().method1();
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling method1 from method2 is simple:

```
new M2().method1();
```

Since a static inner class is pretty much a regular class.

However, since the inner class is static, it does not correspond to any instance of the outer class, and since method2 is not static it must be invoked on an instance, so there's no direct way of calling that method, you still need an instance of the outer class to call the method:

```
new Test().method2();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
public class Test{
void method2(){
    System.out.println("This is outer class method");
}

static class M2{
    void method1(){
        System.out.println("This is method1 in class m2");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){       
    M2 m2=new M2();
    m2.method1();
}
```

}

Comment: +1.It works perfect.But OP expects some explanation,that why it works :)

Answer (score 0):

As usual in order to call a non-static method, you need an instance to invoke it on. Either make the methods static or create instances of the classes. Here is one option on how to get your code [working](http://ideone.com/5QUR2C):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class main{
    static void method2(){
        System.out.println("This is outer class method");
    }

    static class M2{
        static void method1(){
            System.out.println("This is method1 in class m2");
            method2();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        M2.method1();
        //test a=new test();
        //a.method2();
    }
}
```